# Call jquery method from one js to another .js document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call the jquery function from one .js file to another .js file. please see my code sample here. I want call a `slide()` method from ChartCallback.js file.

### ChartWebControl.js

```
var Accordian = (function () {
        "use strict";
        var Accordian = {
            slide: function () {
                   debugger;
               alert("event trigger");
            }
        };
        return Accordian;
    }());
```

### ChartCallBack.js

```
this.FocusChart = ChartCallBack.FocusChart;

ChartCallBack.FocusChart = function () {


        console.log(window);
        console.log(Accordian);
        Accordian.slide(); //while call this "slide" is undefined exception thrown
}
```

I checked `"Accordian"` it was initialize with `slide()` method  before load the `ChartCallback.js`.

What i did wrongly here. anyone could solve my problem.

Comment: I tried it in jsfiddle and it works. Could you create a fiddle where it fails?

Comment: yes.. but in jsfiddle the code's are in same page. so it was worked.. but i have separated two files. that' s problem

Comment: How do you load these files?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you include both files in one html document, this should work fine. Just be aware that the order of inclusion will matter here.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ChartWebControl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ChartCallBack.js"></script>
```

In essence this will load both scripts into the same page.

If you meant to communicate with two separate html files, this is not possible without some kind of server communication.